# Does adding extra loop at the end of n(log n) algorithm affect the complexity?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I wrote an algorithm to find length of longest increasing sequence in an array.

The algorithm has an array **m** which will contain the sequence but in some conditions, it doesn't contain the exact sequence. So in such case, I record the index and value which needs to be changed.

This algorithm is n(log n)

Now, to find the actual sequence, I loop through the array **m** and replace the value recorded in another array. Will my algorithm now still have the complexity if n(log n) ?

Below is the code in C#:

```
        int[] b = { 1, 8, 5, 3, 7, 2, 9 };

        int k = 1;

        int i = 1;
        int N = b.Length; 

        List<int> m = new List<int>();
        int[] lup = new int[b.Length];

        m.Add(0);
        m.Add(b[0]);
        lup[0] = 0;
        while (i < N)
        {
            if (b[i] >= m[k])
            {
                k = k + 1;
                m.Add(b[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                if (b[i] < m[1])  
                {
                    m[1] = b[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    int j;
                    j = Binary_Search(m, b[i], m.Count - 1);
                    //if the item to be replaced was not the last element, record it
                    if (m[j] > b[i] && j != k)
                    {
                        lup[j] = m[j];
                    }
                    m[j] = b[i];

                }
            }
            i = i + 1;

        }

        Console.WriteLine("The Input Sequence is : " + string.Join("\t", b));
        Console.WriteLine("Length of Longest Up Sequence is : " + k.ToString());

        List<int> result = new List<int>();

        // create result based on m and lup
        //DOES THIS LOOP EFFECT PERFORMANCE??
        for(int x = 1; x < m.Count; x++)
        {
            if (lup[x] == 0)
            {
                result.Add(m[x]);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(lup[x]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The complexity is O(n log n) and also Theta(n log n). The big-O notation is there for a reason. Learn what it means and use it when it fits.

Comment: By the way, it's important that the addition has constant time (or at most logarithmic time). The order of the algorithm could change if you were using Java, where List is an interface, and the implementation of a List by a linked list could make the addition operation linear instead of constant, so that the whole procedure becomes quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct. Adding this loop is n*(log(n)+1) so it's still n*log(n).

Comment: You are assuming that when someone says complexity f(n), they mean O(f(n)). You should state that assumption explicitly, and use the correct notation to be correct.